# Symfony: SensioLabs Connect & Bundles

Tags: symfony

I'm starting with Symfony3 and I have two beginner questions:

1. Is there a good repository for Symfony Bundles? I found some, but they all lack a category system. Is this a downsite for Symfony, that you have to scan all bundles in their sourcecode?? The names and supershort descriptions tell you almost nothing about the bundles...
2. I've tried to join the https://connect.sensiolabs.com community but somehow I don't see anything. I just can edit my profile. It says "profile completion: 50%" and asks me for some more accounts on Github etc. (which I don't have). Am I missing something? I thought there will be a nice board etc.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Keep in mind that S3 was just released about a week ago.  Many popular 3rd party bundles are not yet S3 ready.  Read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 1):

http://knpbundles.com/ contains thousands of bundles to use. Also https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony have awesome bundles.

Usually whenever you want to do a feature you'll google bundles that support this feature. Hence the name gets relevant.